# Angular Modal throws error as "Cannot read property 'removeChild' of null"

Tags: angular, model

I have closed all the models opened in the application as below in app component when session timeout expires

```
        let modal = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.modal'));

        if(modal.length >0){
        modal.forEach(node => {
          node.remove();
        });
        }
        let backdrop = Array.from(document.querySelectorAll('.modal-backdrop'));


        if(backdrop.length >0){
        backdrop.forEach(node => {
          node.remove();
        });   
        }
```

But When I re login and open the models, I am getting the following error as **Cannot read property 'removeChild' of null**

But It works as expected if the page is reloaded at the time of session timeout.

I use the following code to reopen the model after login

```
this.bsModalRef = this.modalService.show(ItemDetailComponent, {
    initialState: {
      thisItemId: cell.getRow().getData().traceEntId
    },
    class: 'modal-lg'
  });
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Where is this `removeChild` appear?

Comment: While opening the model in the respective component

Comment: Then the error is like it stats: Your property in the model in the respective component is `null`

Comment: is there an any way to fix it up

Comment: Check before if it is null

Comment: but I should be able to open the component in model window

Comment: Then set the model to a initial value which is not null